# Keep executing an observable in repository layer when UseCase is disposed

Tags: android, rx-java2, clean-architecture

What is the proper way to execute some kind of "background" action, like saving data in the database, when this action is triggered by a presenter, but the presenter is disposing the observable before the end of the query?

Should I decouple my Repository observable from the UseCase one?

#### Example

I'me developing an Android application following the Clean Architecture and MVP patterns, using RxJava and Dagger.

In a Dialog, I'm listing devices, and can connect to one when selecting it in the list. 
When an element in the list is clicked, the dialog is dismissed, and I'm setting/saving this device as the 'current' device in my repository layer and animating a logo in the toolbar of the activity (somehow like the Chromecast is doing).

In my presenter, I dispose my UseCases when the view is detached, so if the saving is not complete when the dialog is dismissed, the observable gets disposed and the device is not set as 'current' device.

#### Presenter

```
@Override
public void deviceClicked(String id) {
    getMvpView().dismissView();
    mConnectToDeviceUseCase.execute(id, new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Timber.d("Connected to device");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Timber.e("Error while connecting to device: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

#### UseCase

```
public class ConnectToDeviceUseCase extends UseCaseCompletableWithParameter<String, DevicesRepository> {

    @Inject
    public ConnectToDeviceUseCase(DevicesRepository DevicesRepository,
                                   @Named("Thread") Scheduler threadScheduler,
                                   @Named("PostExecution") Scheduler postExecutionScheduler) {
        super(devicesRepository, threadScheduler, postExecutionScheduler);
    }

    @Override
    protected Completable buildObservable(String id) {
        Timber.d("GetDevicesUseCase buildObservable");

        return repository.connectToDevice(id);
    }
}
```

#### Repository

```
private ReplaySubject<DeviceConnection> connectionStatus = ReplaySubject.create();
```

...

```
@Override
public Completable connectToDevice(String id) {
    Timber.d("connectToDevice IN");
    return mDLNADataSource.getDevices()
            .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
            .filter(item -> item.id().equals(id))
            .firstOrError()
            .flatMapCompletable(this::saveAsCurrent)
            .doOnSubscribe(a ->
                    {
                        Timber.d("connectToDevice doOnSubscribe");
                        connectionStatus.onNext(DeviceConnection.builder().setStatus(DeviceConnection.STATUS_CONNECTING).build());
                    }
            )
            .doOnComplete(() ->
                    {
                        Timber.d("connectToDevice doOnComplete");
                        connectionStatus.onNext(DeviceConnection.builder().setStatus(DeviceConnection.STATUS_CONNECTED).build());
                    }
            )
            .doOnError(a ->
                    {
                        Timber.d("connectToDevice doOnError");
                        connectionStatus.onNext(DeviceConnection.builder().setStatus(DeviceConnection.STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED).build());
                    }
            )
            .doOnDispose(() ->
            {
                Timber.d("connectToDevice doOnDispose");
            });

}
```

Comment: The Use Case can only dispose of the observable when the observable is completed; anything else can lead to data corruption. Perhaps you have a second meaning for the term "use case" here? One for user-prompted-action and one for functional-usage?

Comment: The UseCase is also called "interactor" in the Clean Architecture Domain layer.
I think my question can be rephrased to 'how to properly organize my data layer'... Maybe using a PublishSubject instead of a completable, and executing the save action on a separate thread, with a lock?

Answer (score 0):

I am neither java nor Android expert but what you have described in your question sounds like controlflow issue to me.
If you trigger some async activity (e.g. save) you should also connect the cleanup to it. One possible solution could be using the concept of a "future" or "promise". Another one could be the actor pattern where save and cleanup would be messages executed sequentially.